# Is a file statistics reset without a reboot possible?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I know about a possibility to reset wait stats via DBCC SQLPERF (N'sys.dm_os_wait_stats', CLEAR)
Are there any possibilities to do the same to data file statistics without a server restart? It's about information delivered by querying sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats.

Comment: restoring from a backup led to negative values of the difference

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not. You should be able to diff the results of the query against it, though.